# Can't get my Listview to show letters from textbox

Tags: c#

I have two TextBoxes: the first one is Firstname and the other is Lastname.  I can get the values from the firstName TextBox but not the lastName TextBox.

The TextBoxes are inside CustomerFrame class.

```
if (customerframe.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    listView1.Items.Add("[{0}, {1}]", customerframe.firstName, customerframe.lastName);
}
```

Here is the CustomerFrame class:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstName = tbFirstName.Text;
    lastName = tbLastName.Text;
}
```

In the ListView only the letters from the firstName appears. Whats wrong?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you forgot to write `string.Format`. The code should read

```
var item = string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", customerframe.firstName, customerframe.lastName);
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

The way the code is written right now, it calls [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6a9wz99.aspx) overload of the `Add` method by mistake, when you were intending to call [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttzhk9y3.aspx) overload instead.

In the overload you do end up calling (with the three parameters), the second parameter is the item text -- what will be displayed. That's why only the `firstName` shows in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for Add is

`(string key, string text, string imageKey)`

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6a9wz99.aspx

I believe you're looking for:

`listView1.Items.Add(String.Format("[{0}, {1}]", customerframe.firstName, customerframe.lastName));`